# String diffs as List

Tags: scala

Given:

```
val foo = "123456"
val bar = "24"
```

Now make diffs of this strings:

```
foo diff bar
// String = 1356
```

This returns the differences as concatenated String. **Is it possible to get a List of the diffs?** Something like:

```
foo magicDiff bar
// List[String] = List("1", "3", "56")
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to *enlist* diffs with the use of *single built-in* method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scala> foo.split(bar.toArray).toList.filterNot(_.isEmpty)
res0: List[String] = List(1, 3, 56)
```

Comment: except, it would not work the same way diff will in case of repeats (try `val foo = "123456123"` with both to see the difference)

Comment: except, it would not work if the element you want to filter out is consecutive.   

val fullString = "1234567"
val bar = "45"
fullString.split(bar.toArray).toList //res1: List[String] = List(123, , 67)
fullString.split(bar.toArray).toList.size // 3